# Uploading local sql server tables to a hosting server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please, apart from management studio, is there any other tool which can be used to connect to a database on a hosting server online. Because I've tried so many times with management studio with the right credentials but I'm still not able to connect. I've disable all firewalls, made the right configuration but I'm still not able to connect.

when I connect I get this error

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing 
a connection to  SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is 
known.)  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)
```

Comment: [Resolving “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

Comment: `No such host is known.` - The problem isn't the credentials...

Comment: have gone through all that process and still doesn't work.